# Nonlinear system of equations / factoring two-variable cubic over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: factoring, nonlinear-system

About halfway through a homework problem, I end up with a three-way identity:

$$\frac{uw}{v+w} = \frac{uv}{u+w} = \frac{vw}{u+v}$$

(I say *I end up with...*, but this is the method suggested by my professor.)  What I have to do is show that $u=v=w=1$.  I started by simplifying two of the expressions:

$$\frac{u}{u+w} = \frac{w}{u+v}$$

From this, we can conclude that $v = \frac{\left(u+w \right)w-u^2}{u}$, which can then be substituted into another of the above identities, say $\frac{uw}{v+w} = \frac{uv}{u+w}$.

Eventually, this leads to a fourth-degree polynomial equation:

$$
\begin {align}
\ w^4+3w^3u - w^2 u^2 - 4w u^3 + u^4 &= 0 \\
\ (w - u)(w^3 + 4w^2 u + 3wu^2 - u^3) &= 0 \\
\end{align}
$$

I factored the above by long division, simply because I knew that $u = w$ is supposed to be a solution. Beyond this point, though, I'm not sure what to do. Wolfram Alpha says the cubic is irreducible; that seems totally plausible if we're working in $\mathbb{Q}[u,w]$. But this is a third-degree polynomial: Shouldn't there be at least one linear factor in $\mathbb{R}[u,w]$?

I was able to substitute to get the equation $k^3 + 4k^2 + 3k - 1 = 0$, which I was able to rework into the depressed cubic $z^3 - \frac{7}{3}z -  \frac{7}{27} = 0$. I tried using Bombelli's method, which gave me

$$z = \sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{54}+\frac{7}{54}i\sqrt{755}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{7}{54}-\frac{7}{54}i\sqrt{755}}$$

I set the first term on the RHS to $p+qi$, cubing both sides and trying to match up the real parts (i.e., $p\left(p^2 - 3q^2 \right) = 7 / 54$), but that's as far as I got.

So my question:  Is this a viable route toward the answer?  If so, how might I proceed?  Do I need to take a few steps back?  Or should I go back to my first step and pick a totally different path? (Perhaps there's a way to keep the degree of the equation down by starting again at the beginning?)  I realize the answers to all of these questions may be yes, and so, if they are, hopefully I can get suggestions for multiple methods: I'm really just interested in methodology here, I guess.

One final note:  $u, v, w$ are the weights of three points using barycentric coordinates. (Hopefully I'm saying that right.) Therefore, each must be positive; that's the only restriction I'm aware of. Of the approximate roots of the depressed cubic — Wolfram gives the exact answers as complex, though the approximations have no imaginary part — only one is positive; therefore there's only one extra answer I'm concerned about eliminating — either by not letting it in in the first place or by being able to explain why it's not a valid answer. (I realize there's a lot here, but hopefully it's clear; please let me know if anything isn't.)

Comment: Why can't we have $ u=v=w$ equal to some other constant? Since you said you used barycentric coordinates, do you want those to sum up to 1?

Comment: @CalvinLin, Good point. I was just repeating what I had in my notebook; I was probably using homogeneous coordinates. Basically, $u = v = w$.

Answer (score 1):

Making the assumption that $u,v,w$ are positive (last paragraph), we get that

$$ \frac{ uvw} { v^2 + vw } = \frac{ uvw } { w^2 + uw} = \frac {uvw}{u^2 + uv} ,$$

and hence that

$$ v^2 + vw = w^2 + wu = u^2 + uv .$$

Now, take the difference of 2 equations, we get that

$$ v^2 - w^2 = w (u-v), w^2 - u^2 = u(v-w), u^2 - v^2 = v(w-u). $$

Multiplying these 3 equations together, we get

$$ (v-w)(v+w)(w-u)(w+u)(u-v)(v+u) = (u-v)(v-w)(w-u)wuv \\ \Rightarrow (u-v)(v-w)(w-u) [ (v+w) ( w+u)(u+v) - uvw] = 0 . $$

Since $ (v+w) ( w+u)(u+v) \geq 2 \sqrt{vw} 2 \sqrt{wu} 2 \sqrt{uv} > uvw$, hence we must have $ (v-w)(w-u)(u-v) = 0$. It is easy to show that if $ v=w$, then we must have $w=u$ in the original equations.

Hence, $ u=v=w$ is the only set of solutions.

Comment: Thanks, Calvin.  I follow up through the step where you multiply the three equations together.  After that, it looks like something got left out (i.e., the RHS of the equation that follows). At the moment, I have two questions for you, but I'll wait to see if the fix clears either of them up.

Comment: Both questions got answered :). Thank you again!